# How to get the UNC path of partition?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, cmd.exe

How can i get the UNC path of the partitions on my hard disk in Windows 7? I mean paths to be displayed in this way:

\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1
\Device\Harddisk0\Partition2
\Device\Harddisk0\Partition3

Is it possible to do that from Command Prompt?

Comment: That is not an [UNC](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Naming_Convention) path, but an [NT Object Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Manager_%28Windows%29) path.

Answer (score 1):

You can create script for [`diskpart`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415).

Example script `ListPartition.txt`:

```
select disk 0
list partition
```

Than execute this script with `diskpart.exe -s ListPartition.txt`.

---

If you can use PowerShell it is even easier. Use [`Get-Partition`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848682.aspx).

```
Get-Partition
```

For exact output you wished you can use next script:

```
Get-Partition -DiskNumber 0 | ForEach-Object {"\Device\Harddisk$($_.DiskNumber)\Partition$($_.PartitionNumber)"}
```

You can also execute powershell directly from *cmd* with:

```
powershell -Command "Get-Partition -DiskNumber 0 | ForEach-Object {\"\Device\Harddisk$($_.DiskNumber)\Partition$($_.PartitionNumber)\"}"
```

Note the escaped `"` with `\"`

All these commands must be execured with elevated priviletges (*Run as Administrator*).

Comment: Diskpart doesn't list the partitions with their NT paths, and if i try to use powershell it says that it doesn't recognize the term Get-Partition.